# Retornar menor valor de uma lista - Lisp

Tags: lista, lisp

Quero retornar o menor valor de uma lista com uma função iterativa em Lisp.
O código que tenho é o seguinte:

```
 (defun rmin (lista)
(let ((minim (first lista))) (loop for a in (lista) (if (< a minim) (minim a))) minim))
```

A minha ideia era substituir a variável inicial `(minim)` pelo `a` quando encontra um valor menor na lista, e no final do ciclo retornar o menor valor encontrado.

Comment: Qual compilador ou interpretador você está usando para rodar o programa?